# Force CMD to update pipe to clipboard

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, pipe, clipboard

I'm running ffmpeg to find scenechanges successfully, but was hoping to ouput ffmpeg's STDERR to another program, starting by testing it by piping to the clipboard. Capturing STDERR alone `2 |` makes ffmpeg think it should output using format 2 through a pipe, but I found I could successfully capture STDOUT & STDERR together:

```
ffmpeg -i "inputfile.mkv" -filter_complex "select='gte(scene,0.4)',metadata=print:file=FrameDifferences.txt" -f null - 2>&1 | clip
```

Problem is, when I pipe to the clipboard, I only get an update once the program has finished running. As one of my reasons for piping STDERR was to get progress updates on the encoding, this was rather sad. Is there a simple way to force CMD to periodically update the pipe? Or is this a limitation to using the clipboard such that I'll have to begin testing by preparing another program to receive the pipe?

Comment: the problem is, `cmd` can only output to one destination. That's either your screen, OR a file, OR the clipboard. You need a tool to "fork" the output to two destinations. Google for "tee for windows".

Comment: Use the `-progress` option.

Comment: Again, tried that already. :( Problem is, anything I'm sending into the pipe only shows up once the program is finished. Adding the extra info from -progress into the pipe doesn't make a difference, since it still only shows up once the program is done.

Comment: I'm only worried about the pipe to the clipboard, and the pipe to the clipboard only changes when everything is done. And no updates to the pipe are taking place during the encode. :(

Comment: Write progress to a file and tail it.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid writing to files, but if the pipe can't be updated during encode, that's definitely the route I'll take. Because for some reason, the files do update during encode...

Comment: Because you redirect to files (not pipe). To capture STDERR alone: `command 2>&1 1>nul |clip` (in case it's useful to you; still same issue)